# difference between phpmyadmin and php PDO

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm running a query in Phpmyadmin and also execute the same query with php PDO but results are not equal. What could be wrong ? 
This is query :

```
SELECT dim_date_key as date ,dim_jdate_key as jdate, SUM(val_call_counts) as count
FROM `fact_j_service_location_table_ts` 
WHERE `dim_time_stamp` >= '1426451400'
AND `dim_time_stamp` < '1427311800' 
AND dim_service_id  = 2  
GROUP BY dim_date_key  
LIMIT 0,10;
```

phpmyadmin :

```
date        jdate       count   
20150316    13931225    5711    
20150317    13931226    6170    
20150318    13931227    7244    
20150319    13931228    7825    
20150320    13931229    6261    
20150321    13940101    4622    
20150322    13940102    4513    
20150323    13940103    4671
```

but php returns :

```
20150316    13931225    6295    
20150317    13931226    6170    
20150318    13931227    7244    
20150319    13931228    14170   
20150320    13931229    6261    
20150321    13940101    4622    
20150322    13940102    16879   
20150323    13940103    4671
```

and here is php script :

```
$sql = "SELECT dim_date_key as date ,dim_jdate_key as jdate, SUM(val_call_counts) as count
    FROM `fact_j_service_location_table_ts` 
    WHERE `dim_time_stamp` >= '1426451400'
    AND `dim_time_stamp` < '1427311800' 
    AND dim_service_id  = 2  
    GROUP BY dim_date_key  
    LIMIT 0,10;";
$db = new PDO($server ,$username, $pass, $opt);
$this_result = $db->prepare($sql);
$this_result->execute();
//$error = $this_result->errorInfo();

$res = $this_result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Without seeing your PHP/PDO code it would be impossible to know.

Comment: @JayBlanchard as you asked , I've edited description and added php script too.

Comment: A little speculation: MySQL doesn't guarantee an order unless you specify one, so it is possible that the same query with no `ORDER BY` run at different times will return rows in a different order. Using a `LIMIT` clause on such a query could potentially select a different batch of rows. I'm not sure how this works with `GROUP BY` in the mix, but it would be interesting to see the results without the `LIMIT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but count and date is reservated keyword in MySQL so if you try to escape them, it should work :

```
AS `date`
AS `count`
```